# ADF TreeTable: Calling a method on click of expand button of master row

Tags: oracle-adf, treetableview

I need to call a method whenever expand button of master row in treetable, is clicked. How can i achieve it? I put image link in nodestamp , but method bind in its action listner is not getting fired.

Answer (score 1):

You might try selectionlistener or rowdisclosurelistener instead. Check docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_treeTable.html).